# Capistrano bundle gems before sending to server

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, capistrano

My servers don't have access to external resources (gems, etc), so I manually run

```
bundle package
```

then upload the code and run

```
bundle install --local
```

How can I get the same behaviour out of Capistrano? Using the Bundler recipe, tries to install the bundles on the server. Whereas I'd like to;

On the build machine

1. Checkout from SVN
2. run bundle package
3. zip and upload the artifact

On the application server

1. Expand the Zip artifact
2. run bundle install --local
3. start the server

I tried

```
after("deploy:update_code") do
    system("cd #{copy_cache} && bundle package")
end
```

But that runs the checkout and upload, there didn't seem to be a place to attach after the checkout, but before the zip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the best way to do this is to, run bundle package on the development workstation, and then commit the bundled gems to source control, then run;

```
bundle install --deployment
```

Comment: We have this same problem but we don't want to add our gems to git.